# Colour mapping in 3D matplotlib figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors

I have a numpy array with random coordinates x1 to x3 (shape 100,3)

Each set of coordinates (point) has an associated y value I calculated using my function stored in its own array right now (100,1)

I want to create a 3D(4D) scatterplot, with the coordinates on the 3 axes and using colour to show the y_value for each point.

I have this right now:

```
rand_coords = np.random.rand(100, 3) #example
x1_values = rand_coords[:, 0]
x2_values = rand_coords[:, 1]
x3_values = rand_coords[:, 2]
y_values = calculate_fitness_var(a_shape, em, rand_coords)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
scatter = ax.scatter(x1_values, x2_values, x3_values, c=y_values, cmap='viridis', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('coordinate 1')
ax.set_ylabel('coordinate 2')
ax.set_zlabel('coordinate 3')
ax.set_title('Fitness for coordinates')
fig.colorbar(scatter, label='Fitness')

plt.show()
```

This works, except for the colouration. I can't get the colours to represent y, even though y_values is assigned to c. I thought the chosen colourmap might be the problem but it doesn't work with others either... RIght now it gives me random colours and a white to black colourbar for y. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong
Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: the specific issue is "UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored"

Comment: Can you please give us the version of matplotlib you're using

Comment: `y_values` is an empty list or similar.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: print `y_values`

Comment: Using, e.g., `y_values=np.arange(100)/100` your code is just fine, apparently it is `calculate_fitness_var`